# I would like to know how to create a button that shows one final result based on the radio buttons chosen

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to create a button that shows one final result based on the radio buttons chosen.

For example if 'Male is selected and if 'bmi is under 18.5' then answer is "light training needed".  Can anybody help pls?

```
<form>
    Gender:<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male"/>Male
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female"/>Female
    <br/>
    <span id="genderresult"></span>
    <br/>
    Body Mass Index:<br/>
    <select id="bmi" onchange="showChange()">
        <option value="under 18.5">&lt;18.5</option>
        <option value="18.5 to 24.9">18.5-24.9</option>
        <option value="25 to 29">25-29</option>
        <option value="over 30">30+</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <span id="bmiresult"></span>
</form>

<script>
    var radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
    var genderresult = document.getElementById("genderresult");
    var bmiresult = document.getElementById("bmiresult");

    radioButtons.forEach(r=>{
        r.onclick = function(e){
            genderresult.innerHTML = "You are "+r.value;
        }
    });

    function showChange(){
        var bmi = document.getElementById("bmi").value;
        bmiresult.innerHTML = "Your body mass index is "+bmi;

        if(bmi=="over 30"){
            bmiresult.innerHTML += "<br/>Consider losing weight";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, maybe i can provide one solution. You wanna do first of all a selection from wherever and after that you wanna choose a choice from radio buttons section. Okay, you can use a listener that only wait when you choose one of the radio button that you selected. I mean, if write something and after that you select the radio button you know that the variable in which you wrote, have something and you can select a choice.

Let me be more clear. I mean that you have a text field and after that you have a radio button.
      If you don't write something and you select one of the raddio button choices you display an errot but if you wrote before and it was saved in a variable that already is not undefined then you can select raddio button and manipulatr the output.